# Syntax Urgent only one line | jquery

Tags: jquery

edit to give more code:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $(document).on('change', 'select[name="location"]', function(){
if ($(this).val() !== '') {
  $(".ea-standard form div.step").show(); //show all
  $(".ea-standard form div.step").not(':eq(1)').hide(); //then hide some
  $("#location-icon-jquery i").removeClass( "current-icon-yellow" ).addClass("active-icon-green");
    $("#hospital-icon-jquery i").addClass("current-icon-yellow");
} } ) } );

jQuery(function($){
  $(document).on('change', 'select[name="service"]', function(){
if ($(this).val() !== '') {
  $(".ea-standard form div.step").show(); //show all
  $(".ea-standard form div.step").not(':eq(2)').hide(); //then hide some
  $("#hospital-icon-jquery i").removeClass( "current-icon-yellow" ).addClass("active-icon-green");
   $("#doctor-icon-jquery i").addClass("current-icon-yellow");
} } ) } );

jQuery(function($){
$( '<div class="container"><div class="row icon-appointment"> <span class="col-md-2" id="location-icon-jquery"> <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt current-icon-yellow"></i> </span> <span class="col-md-2" id="hospital-icon-jquery"> <i class="fas fa-hospital cc_cursor" ></i> </span> <span class="col-md-2"> <i class="fas fa-user-md" id="doctor-icon-jquery"></i> </span> <span class="col-md-2"> <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> </span> <span class="col-md-4"> <i class="far fa-calendar-check"></i> </span></div></div>' ).insertBefore( ".ea-standard" );
} );
```

to give more clear:

```
'<div class="container">
<div class="row icon-appointment">
 <span class="col-md-2" id="location-icon-jquery"> 
<i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt current-icon-yellow">
</i> 
</span>
 <span class="col-md-2" id="hospital-icon-jquery">
 <i class="fas fa-hospital cc_cursor" >
</i> 
</span>
 <span class="col-md-2">
 <i class="fas fa-user-md" id="doctor-icon-jquery">
</i>
 </span> 
<span class="col-md-2">
 <i class="far fa-calendar-alt">
</i>
 </span> 
<span class="col-md-4">
 <i class="far fa-calendar-check">
</i> 
</span>
</div>
</div>
```

---

edit to comment:

```
jQuery(function($){
var spans = $('.icon-appointment span');
spans.on("click", function () {
   var currentSpan = $(this);
   var prevIndex = currentSpan.index() - 1;
   var prevSpan = spans.eq(prevIndex);
   console.log(prevSpan.hasClass('active-icon-green'));
   if (prevSpan.hasClass('active-icon-green') !== true) { 
       alert("you must fill previous step");
   }
});
} );
```

---

**edit:**

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.icon-appointment span').click(function() {
  var self   = $(this),
      index  = self.index()-1
  if (($(this):eq(index)).hasClass('active-icon-green')) {
do something
```

---

I am sorry that un-common question title but my question is this exactly.

```
  if ($(this):eq(index).hasClass('active-icon-green')) {
```

I have above jquery code line. index refers:

```
   $('.icon-appointment span').click(function() {
  var self   = $(this),
      index  = self.index()-1
```

so I want to check if one previous `span` than **clicked** `span under icon-appointment class` has `active-icon-green class` or not.

my js code editor says:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0416.png)

so what is the true syntax? thanks

Comment: `$(this):eq(index)` the `:eq` is wrong

Comment: @epascarello so how can i use :eq in that line?

Comment: It is unclear how this is an JQuery collection, but it would be `.eq()` since it is not a selector. Your code should just be `if($(this).hasClass('active-icon-green'))`

Comment: @epascarello i editted question can you look at again please?

Comment: And my last comment is still correct....

Comment: @epascarello but i want to check previous span than this.if i am not wrong, your code checks this, not previous span  than this???

Comment: Well the problem you have is "this" is the current span... there is no indexes for that element

Comment: @epascarello oh this is my mistake, i must write parent class instead of this

Comment: What do you mean by "Syntax urgent"? (You appear to have made updates at the start of this question, rather than at the end, so new readers will now not have an easy time of understanding what is required here).

Comment: @halfer i think it is only syntax issue and could be solved by expert easly so urgent question.edits on top are for author of answer.can you say me what must i learn and with which order to be a good php developer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax errors in your code. You are using the "CSS Slector" syntax instead of the method. The other issue is you are expecting $(this) to be all the spans when it is just the one you clicked on.

```
var spans = $('.icon-appointment span');
spans.on("click", function () {
   var currentSpan = $(this);
   var prevIndex = currentSpan.index() - 1;
   var prevSpan = spans.eq(prevIndex);
   console.log(prevSpan.hasClass('active-icon-green'));
});
```

Now if they were siblings in the HTML, you can just use prev()

```
var spans = $('.icon-appointment span');
spans.on("click", function () {
   var currentSpan = $(this);
   var prevSpan = currentSpan.prev();
   console.log(prevSpan.hasClass('active-icon-green'));
});
```

And after the 4th edit....

The class is on the `<i>` not the span. So you would need to look at the `<i>`

```
var prevSpan = spans.eq(prevIndex);
var prevIcon = prevSpan.next("i");
console.log(prevIcon.hasClass('active-icon-green'));
```

Comment: you understand what I want, thanks but I have a last question and it is probably about syntax.I want to check hassClass true or not and alert depends this answer but my code alert in any span.I editted question again, can you look at please?

Comment: I am sorry that un-clear comments before but also your code says false for every span

Comment: Well are you sure the class is on that span? I can only guess with the minimal amount of data you gave me.

Comment: I editted question to give more code.

Comment: ANd the class is not on the span....

Comment: I editted var spans to .icon-appointment span i but doesnt change

Comment: The class you are looking for is on the `<i>` not the span....

Comment: yes, i am sorry that i wrote wrong in my question.the class in <i> but i changed var spans to .icon-appointment span i after i notice my wrong but result didnt change

Comment: thanks for your help.I dont know why but I get up bad concentrate today and this bad mood continue to all day and I take your many time to easy question.I editted my before functions and now it works.